# Show 'please wait' during web service call

Tags: android, multithreading, web-services, android-asynctask

I have an activity which checks username availability via .net web services, I need to show a 'please wait' message during the call as it can take a second or two - I have experimented with AsyncTask and Threading but the problem I have is I actually want to block the main (and only) thread until the web service call has completed as I am depending on the result from it to process other logic.

I have tried allsorts but no joy - can anyone help please?

As requested, here is a section of my code :

```
private OnClickListener RegistrationListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ClearFieldHighlighting();
        if (ValidateData()) {
            if (IsOnline()) {
                if (UsernameIsAvailable()) {
                    try {
                        iNETUserID = CreateOnlineUser();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
```

..more code..
}

Here is the 'UsernameIsAvailable' function :

public boolean UsernameIsAvailable() {

```
    Boolean bUsernameIsAvailable = false;

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(TA.sNAMESPACE,
            TA.METHOD_IsUsernameAvailable);
    request.addProperty("sUsername", sEmail);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
            TA.WEBSERVICES_URL);

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(TA.SOAP_ACTION_IsUsernameAvailable,
                envelope);
        SoapObject thisresponse = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

        for (int i = 0; i < thisresponse.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
            Object obj = thisresponse.getProperty(i);
            SoapPrimitive soapPrimitive = (SoapPrimitive) obj;
            bUsernameIsAvailable = Boolean.parseBoolean(soapPrimitive
                    .toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return bUsernameIsAvailable;
}
```

I am using KSoap2 which is an external jar file to handle the web service stuff

Thanks
Mike

Comment: thanks and I do understand I should not block the UI thread, I just need to!  here is a section of my code :



private OnClickListener RegistrationListener = new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
   ClearFieldHighlighting();
   if (ValidateData()) {
    if (IsOnline()) {
     if (UsernameIsAvailable()) {
      try {
       iNETUserID = CreateOnlineUser();
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }

It is the call to UsernameIsAvailable which is causing the problem as it returns a bool result which I need to continue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can structure your code in the following way:

```java
private class MyBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // show dialog
    }
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        // background processing
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        // dismiss dialog
        continueProcessing();
    }
}

private OnClickListener RegistrationListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // non-blocking code

        new MyBackgroundTask().execute();
    }
}

public void continueProcessing() {
    // the rest of the main activity
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should never ever ever block the main-ui thread. Just show a dialog with a message about what is going on. Make sure that the user can't close the dialog. As soon as the AsyncTask or runnable finishes its task just close the dialog.

Use [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html) [setCancelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable%28boolean%29)(false) to make sure the user can't close the dialog

Comment: I +1'd but I don't think that using `setCancelable(false)` is good for usability. The application should be able to cancel the request if the user gets impatient. A better approach would be to show some kind of progress indicator so there is feedback that __something__ is happening.

Comment: I already tried this with asynctask - my main code continues to execute whilst the web service call is running - I don't want this to happen!

Comment: You code your application so that your "main code" waits for the `AsyncTask` to complete. Like Kevin said, you should not block the UI thread because it will make your application unresponsive to the user. If you post some of your code, we can offer more specific help.

Comment: @unluddite: I agree feedback is always a good thing. But Mike wanted the user to wait for the request to respond so i that case setCancelable is a option. But i think (like you) the request should be cancelable if the user wants to.

Mike: Give us a example so we can help you out.

Comment: As you can see, my code posted above calls the web service in the buttons onclicklistener event - is there a way I can improve this?

Comment: Can you post the code as an edit to your question rather than a comment?

Comment: This may sound stupid but have you tried e.printstacktrace() to ensure that there is no exception.

Comment: to be honest no, but the web service call definitely works as it successfully detects whether the account has been registered or not..

Comment: You can move all the blocking code into an `AsyncTask` or `Thread` and wait for it complete before proceeding.

Comment: this is what I thought, I created an asynctask with a progressdialog onPreExecute and ran my web service call in the doInBackground event - then dismissed the progressdialog iin OnPostExecute.  All this achieved was - the web service call ran first, then the main code continued to run (I can tell because it highlighted the email address field to show it was already registered) - then the progressdialog displayed immediately afterwards which almost immediately disappeared!

Comment: Were you waiting for the task to complete before continuing on? This is usually done by starting the `AsyncTask` and then have the task call a function in `onPostExecute` that performs the rest of your main processing. In other words, whatever function starts the `AsyncTask` should start it, stop further processing, and pick up the processing in another function that is called from `onPostExecute`.

Comment: If you like the answer, you should accept/up-vote so that people in the future looking for similar help can find it :)